# remove last 14 digits from string, if there are digits

Tags: powershell

I have a textfile where I store my testname. The testname sometimes has a date afterwards consisting of a 14 digit timestamp. The testname can be:

`data-c(festo1-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(festo1)-win1`

or

`data-c(festo1-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(festo1)-win1_20130620123306`

I want to reuse this file/testname. I need to strip off the timestamp, if there is already one, and add the current timestamp. This is what I got so far:

```
#rescue testname for another run                                                                                                                                                                                                           
$testname = Get-Content "output\testname"

Write-Host Old: $testname

#strip date from testname                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
$testname = $testname.Substring(0,$string.Length - 14)
$olddate = $testname.Substring($string.Length - 14)

Write-Host OldDate: $olddate

#add new Date                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
$startTime = Get-Date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss
$testname += "_"
$testname += $startTime

Write-Host New: $testname
```

How do I check if there is a timestamp/if the last 14 characters are digits? How do I cut the testname from the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this?

```
$filename = "data-c(festo1-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(festo1)-win1_20130620123306"

$filename  -replace '\d{14}$'
```

Comment: I think you need to account for (drop) the underscore between `win1` and the 14 digits.

Comment: Yepp. I just added another replace `$testname = $testname -replace '_'`. to get rid of the underscore. Thanks for this very short solution!

Comment: @mles I believe that you can do it in one shot: `$filename -replace '_\d{14}$'`

Comment: Works in one shot too. Thanks again!